# Regex match all email except within anchor tag one

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find all email addresses from content with html or without html and need to replace with link.

I have below regex for email address find and it's working perfect.

`` (?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\]) ``

Here is demo link to work on with sample data:
https://regexr.com/3v12e

Here is anchor tag regex `(?:(<a[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>))`

So how can find all email address except within anchor tag one:

[image]

Comment: check this https://regexr.com/3v1h5

Comment: @NishitMaheta the problem with that approach is that it will discard emails inside some other tags like `<div>example@gmail.com</div>` not just `<a>` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use something similar to the [trash bin trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html).

You basically search for 3 cases: an 'a' tag, an email, and 'the rest'. You assign a capturing group to any of those 3 cases. Then depending on wether those groups are empty or not, you can do different things. So, this structure: `(A_TAG)|(EMAIL)|([\s\S])` (where `[\s\S]` means any character including new lines)

It is ought to be said that the order is important: You want the first group to be the 'a' tag for discarding it fast. The 'any character' (`[\s\S]`) must be the last option, since if It would be the first one, It would match anything and would give no chance for the other options to match any text.

```js
const regex = /(?:(<a[^>]*>(?:[^<]+)<\/a>))|((?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\]))|([\s\S])/gm;
const str = `example@gmail.com
example@gmail.com
For more information example@gmail.com about I Can Read, 
example@gmail.com please refer to <a href="mailto:do-not@example.com">do-not@example.com</a>our website example@gmail.com
example@gmail.com
 example@gmail.com
    example@gmail.com
  example@gmail.com
  
  sdfsdf example@gmail.com
example@gmail.com sdfsdfsdf`;
let m;

let acc = '';
while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (typeof(m[1])!='undefined') {
        //First group is defined: it will have a <a> tag
        //So we just add it to the acumulator as-is.
        acc += m[1];
    }
    else if (typeof(m[2])!='undefined') {
        //Second group is defined: it will have an email
        //we change it
        acc += '<a href="mailto:' + m[2] + '">' + m[2] + '</a>';
    }
    else {
        //Any other character. We just add to the accumulator
        acc += m[3];
    }
}
console.log(acc);
```

Also, [here](https://regex101.com/r/arN1dj/1/) you can find a demo, just to see visually the different capturing groups. Of course, for the replacements, you would need the extra logic described above.

Comment: Thank you. Work like charm. And thank you for sharing that tutorial link.

Comment: Awesome. It make sense. 
I updated my final code here. https://jsbin.com/fafoqolusu/1/edit?js
- Some how I have to take 0 index on final else other wise it was showing undefined.

It is for CKEditor (html edit plugin) for copy and paste to replace email and url to link.

Comment: See here demo: If I did anything wrong: [Demo Link](https://jsbin.com/koqoyaligu/edit?js,output)

Comment: That is probably because you have some extra capturing group on the regexp you used. For example here: `((?:http(s)?:\/\/.)?` (third) and here `http(s)?` (fourth). It would be better to use non capturing group instead `(?:)`. So the "third" group will be the 'any' character. See the regex here https://regex101.com/r/gxPMcY/2. It should work with `m[3]`. `m[0]` holds the last matched item. So it should be equivalent to the capturing groups since we capture everything. In fact, for your case, you could always use `m[0]` on your accumulator (but checks should be alwas on `m[1]`, `m[2]`...)...

Comment: ... however, I just felt that checking `m[1]` and then use `m[0]` was less 'natural'. So I always used `m[1],m[2],m[3]` for the accumulator

Comment: Great. Thank you. It's really great help.